# how to use remoteFunciton?

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, asset-pipeline

I read this [remoteFunction](https://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP) ..

Below is my code

I basically want to change my userplan when the currency is changed.

like this image

[image]

```
    <tr class="borderTop">
    <td class="formLbl topPadding"><label for="currency.id"><g:message code="currency.label"/></label></td>
    <td class="value ${hasErrors(bean: cifInstance, field: 'currency', 'errors')}">
         <g:select name="currency.id"  value="${cifInstance?.currency?.id}" from="${currency}" optionKey="id"  optionValue="${{it.sym }}" 
            onchange="${remoteFunction(
                controller:'singUp', 
                action:'findUserPlanByCurrency', 
                params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', 
                onComplete:'updateUserPlan(e)')}"
         />

    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="borderTop">
    <td class="formLbl topPadding"><label for="noOfUser"><g:message code="max.user.label"/></label></td>
    <td>
        <g:hiddenField name="userPlan" value="${noOfUser?.id}"/>
        <g:hiddenField name="jumlahuser" id="jumlahuser" value="${noOfUser?.noOfUser}"/>
        <g:select name="userplan.id"  value="${noOfUser?.id}" from="${com.teravin.collection.maintenance.UserPlan.findAllByDeleteFlag('N')}" optionKey="id"  optionValue="${{it.noOfUser }}"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Below is my javascript

```
function updateUserPlan(e) {
    var userplan = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")") // evaluate JSON
    alert(userplan);
    if (userplan) {
            var rselect = document.getElementById('userplan.id')
                // Clear all previous options 
            var l = rselect.length
            while (l > 0) { 
                l-- 
                rselect.remove(l) 
            }
            for (var i=0; i < userplan.length; i++) {
                var userplan2 = userplan[i]
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.text = userplan2.name
                opt.value = userplan2.id
                try {
                    rselect.add(opt, null) // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
                }
                catch(ex) {
                    rselect.add(opt) // IE only
                }
    }
```

so when I change the currency... it will get a value from Controller

```
def findUserPlanByCurrency={
    println "================ "+params
    def currency = Currency.get(params.currency)
    def userplan = UserPlan.findAllByCurrency(currency)
    println "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    if (userplan) {
        if (!params.id) {
            if (userplan.deleteFlag.equals("N"))
                response.status = 405
            else
                response.status = 409
        }
        else {
            if (params.id.equals(userplan.id.toString()))
                response.status = 200
            else{
                if (userplan.deleteFlag.equals("N"))
                    response.status = 405
                else
                    response.status = 409
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        response.status = 200
    }

    if (params.callback) {
        render "${params.callback}(${params as JSON})"
    }
    else {
        render "${params as JSON}"
    }
}
```

When I change the currency, then user plan is not changed ? I am using asset pipeline to call JS, Css and Images too.

Comment: any errors?  e.g. in browser console?

Comment: no error.. it like not get the controller of findUserPlanByCurrency..because  println "================ "+params is not appear in my console

Comment: is your `params.id` filled? can you see it in the controller?

Comment: @injecteer its look like when i change the currency.. itsnot affecting thecontroller ...because...when i changed it.. this firstline isnot printed.. --->> println "================ "+params

Comment: it like any wrong at  controller:'singUp', 
                action:'findUserPlanByCurrency', 
                params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', 
                onComplete:'updateUserPlan(e)')}"

Comment: can you see the ajax call in firebug?

Comment: btw `params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)'` won't work

Comment: @injecteer can you tell me why?

Comment: see the generated html code. usually the url looks like `/singUp/findUserPlanByCurrency/yourId` and is "static", so it cannot be affected by the `this.value`. You can of course include `this.value` in a request, but you have to do it OUTSIDE of g.link/remoteLink etc. tags: `<input onclick="document.location = '${g.createLink( controller:'singUp', action:'findUserPlanByCurrency' )}/' + this.value" value="click"/>`

Comment: oh i see..can you show me an example of g:select with using remote function?

Comment: i see from https://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP , that's using like this "params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<g:select name="currency.id"  value="${cifInstance?.currency?.id}" from="${currency}" optionKey="id"  optionValue="${{it.sym }}" 
                                                     onchange="${remoteFunction(
                                                                  controller:'signUp',
                                                                  action:'findUserPlanByCurrency',
                                                                  params:'\'currency=\' + escape(this.value)', 
                                                                  onComplete:'updateClasses(arguments[0])')}" 
                                          />
```

first : it will process on controller findUserplanByCurrency then render as JSON

and add a a code javascript like this

```
function updateSelect(e, selectId) {
    // The response comes back as a bunch-o-JSON
    var json = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")"); 
    if (json) {     
        var rselect = document.getElementById(selectId);
        // Clear all previous options
        var l = rselect.length;

        while (l > 0) {
            l--;
            rselect.remove(l);
        }



        for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var js = json[i];
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            alert(json);
            opt.text = js.noOfUser;
            opt.value = js.id;
            try {
                rselect.add(opt, null); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
            }
            catch(ex) {
                rselect.add(opt); // IE only
            }
        }       
    }
}
```